# REST service for PUMA search users by createTimestamp

Tags: rest, websphere, websphere-portal

Is it possible to find users by createTimestamp attribute on REST service for PUMA? Search for other attributes works well, but if the type attribute is the dateTime I get different errors, such as http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PM54864.

I need to find users who were created earlier some date.

I tried this:

```
host/wps/um/secure/users/profiles?searchAttributes=createTimestamp>=yyyyMMddHHmmssZ

host/wps/um/secure/users/profiles?searchAttributes=createTimestamp>=yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss

host/wps/um/secure/users/profiles?searchAttributes=createTimestamp>=yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'
```

and even equality is not working

```
host/wps/um/secure/users/profiles?searchAttributes=createTimestamp=yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem through ldap.

```
@Service
public class LdapService {

    @Autowired
    private LdapTemplate ldapTemplate;

    private SearchControls searchControls;

    @PostConstruct
       private void init() {
       searchControls = new SearchControls();
       searchControls.setCountLimit(10000);
       searchControls.setSearchScope(SUBTREE_SCOPE);
    }

    private class MemberMapper implements ContextMapper {

        public Member mapFromContext(Object ctx) {
            Member member = new Member();
            DirContextAdapter adapter = (DirContextAdapter) ctx;
            Attribute valueMail = adapter.getAttributes().get("mail");
            try {
                member.setEmail(valueMail == null ? null : valueMail.get().toString().trim());
            } catch (Exception ignore) {
            }

            Attribute valueCN = adapter.getAttributes().get("cn");
            try {
                member.setLogin(valueCN == null ? null : valueCN.get().toString().trim());
            } catch (Exception ignore) {
            }
            return member;
        }
    }

    public List<Member> getUsersByCreateTimestamp() {
        AndFilter andFilter = new AndFilter();
        andFilter.and(new GreaterThanOrEqualsFilter("createTimestamp" "20160803000000"));
        andFilter.and(new LessThanOrEqualsFilter("createTimestamp", "20160804000000"));

        List<Member> allMembers = new ArrayList<Member>();
        List<Member> members = ldapTemplate.search("", andFilter.encode(), searchControls, new MemberMapper());
        allMembers.addAll(members);
        return allMembers;
    }
```